# How to make an autocomplete search with flexsearch

Tags: php, mysql, autocomplete

In my case of studies, I must to create an autocomplete search with this script. My problem is how to call the database. I don't know.
I suppose I must create another file call search.php

My code

```
<head>
     <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/nextapps-de/flexsearch@master/dist/flexsearch.min.js"></script>


<script src="search.php"></script>

<style>
        table{
            width: 300px;
            table-layout: fixed;
        }
        td, tr{
            border: none;
        }
        input{
            border: 1px solid #ddd;
            border-radius: 3px;
            outline: none;
            background-color: #f5f5f5;
        }
        input, div{
            padding:5px 5px;
            width: 100%;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        #suggestions div{
            padding: 10px 0;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
            overflow: hidden;
            white-space: nowrap;
            text-overflow: ellipsis;
        }
    </style>

</head>
```

```
  <div><input type="text" placeholder="Search ..." onkeyup="show_results.call(this);"></div>
  <div id="suggestions"></div>

</div>


<script>
  (function(){

    var index = new FlexSearch({

      encode: "advanced",
      tokenize: "reverse",
      suggest: true
    });

    var container = document.getElementById("suggestions");

    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){

      index.add(i, data[i]);
    }

    window.show_results = function(){

      var results = index.search(this.value, 10);
      var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
      var entry, tmp;

      for(var i = 0; i < results.length; i++){

        entry = document.createElement("div");
        entry.textContent = data[results[i]];
        fragment.appendChild(entry);
      }

      while((tmp = container.firstChild)){

        container.removeChild(tmp)
      }

      container.appendChild(fragment);
    };

  }());
</script>
```

my search.php, I tried this code, but on how to take the seach keywords make by someone.

```
<?php
        $terms = strtolower($_GET["q"]);

        $Qcheck = $Db->prepare('select distinct products_id as id,
    products_description as description
                                            from :table_products_description
                                            where products_description LIKE :terms
                                            limit 10
                                          ');
        $Qcheck->bindValue(':terms', '%' . $terms . '%');
        $Qcheck->execute();

        $list = $Qcheck->rowCount() ;

        if ($list > 0) {
          $array = [];

          while ($value = $Qcheck->fetch() ) {
            $array[] = $value;
          }

          $json_response = json_encode($array); 

          echo $json_response;
?>
```

I expect inside the input field the search result across the database

Comment: Looks like you might be missing some code. You seem to be on the right track as you call `onkeyup="show_results.call(this);"`. This attempts to call a function that might not exist on the page thus nothing happens.

Comment: @khuderm I am base on this link demo https://github.com/nextapps-de/flexsearch/tree/master/demo . after I don't how to make for the php / mysql search

Answer (score 0):

I would like to help you. First of all I cannot check your php code, so please check the php returns a json encoded string. Then the solution to your intend is as follow.

Replace the last line in *search.php* by these two:

```php
header('Content-Type: text/javascript');
echo 'var data = ' . $json_response . ';';
```

That's all :)